# beamer: footnoterange in columns environment does not work

Tags: beamer

I want to use `footnoterange` in beamer's `columns` environment, but

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{1. footnote}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      text
      \begin{footnoterange}
        \footnote{lorem}
        \footnote{ipsum}
      \end{footnoterange}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{2. footnote[frame]}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      text
      \begin{footnoterange}
        \footnote[frame]{dolor}
        \footnote[frame]{sit}
      \end{footnoterange}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

has the following problems:

1. lorem and ipsum are footnoted, but only en dash is shown and the numbers are missing: [image: the numbers are missing]
2. When trying to use `\footnote[frame]`, the warning emitted:

   ```
   Package footnoterange Warning: Custom footnote-numbers used in a footnoterange
   (footnoterange)                environment: Footnote with natural number
   (footnoterange)                3 was renumbered to frame on input line 16.

   ! Missing number, treated as zero.
   <to be read again> 
                      f
   l.16 \end{frame}
   ```

   <s>which can be ignored</s> I forcibly compile by ignoring the warnings, but `\footnote[frame]` does not work: [image: does not work]

How to fix these?

My environment:

- pdfLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
- LuaLaTeX 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)
- XeLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)
- beamer 2017/01/23 v3.41
- footnoterange 2012/02/17 v1.0a

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with the bibliography package `biblatex`? If not, you might want to re-tag your question to avoid confusion. I can reproduce your problem, but I don't think that `\footnote[frame]` is supposed to work and that the error (!) can be ignored - it's an error after all. The first frame I would expect to work, but it didn't show the numbers as in your test.

Comment: @moewe Ah, yes, I want to use biblatex for citation but actually this is not a problem on biblatex. I deleted the tag. I mean a PDF is created if I ignore the error, of course the behavior of `\footnote[frame]` is unfavorable.

Comment: @kwsm Even if something resembling a pdf is created, do never ever ignore error messages!

Answer (score 1):

You could fake it:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{1. footnote}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      text$^{\text{1--2}}$
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footnotetext[1]{text}
\footnotetext[2]{text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, that works. But it requires tweaking of the numbers so I'm reluctant to do it. I hope this bug is fixed.